# Finding Upper Bound in a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to solve this question

> Let S be a non-empty set and consider the partially ordered set(P(S
>   ), ⊆). Show that every subset of P(S ) has a least upper bound.

I'm not sure I agree with the premise of the question.

If I take S = N, then I won't have an upper bound for the set of all 
 natural numbers (since it isn't closed).

For example, if S = N, then I could consider the chain:

```
 { {1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, ...}
```

This doesn't have an upper bound since the union of this chain isn't closed

Am I thinking correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the order relation "less than" on the natural numbers with the order relation "is a subset of" on the power set.

The set of all subsets of a set *is* closed under union.
The infinite chain in the question has union all of $ \mathbb{N} $, which is its least upper bound in the subset ordering.

Comment: I've edited the question with an example to illustrate my thinking. As I see it, I could take an infinite chain as subet. The chain doesn't have an upper bound since it isn't closed under union

Comment: @NZ_21 See my edit.